# Points around a circumference C#

Tags: c#, trigonometry

Im trying to get a list of vectors that go around a circle, but i keep getting the circle to go around several times. I want one circel and the dots to be placed along its circumference. I want the first dot to start at 0 and the last dot to end just before 360. Also i need to be able to calculate the spacing by the ammount of points.

```
  List<Vector2> pointsInPath = new List<Vector2>();
    private int ammountOfPoints = 5;
    private int blobbSize = 200;
    private Vector2 topLeft = new Vector2(100, 100);
    private Vector2 blobbCenter;
    private int endAngle = 50;
    private int angleIncrementation;
    public Blobb()
    {
        blobbCenter = new Vector2(blobbSize / 2, blobbSize / 2) + topLeft;
        angleIncrementation = endAngle / ammountOfPoints;

        for (int i = 0; i < ammountOfPoints; i++)
        {
            pointsInPath.Add(getPointByAngle(i * angleIncrementation, 100, blobbCenter));
          //  pointsInPath.Add(getPointByAngle(i * angleIncrementation, blobbSize / 2, blobbCenter));
        }
    }

    private Vector2 getPointByAngle(float angle, float distance, Vector2 centre)
    {
        return new Vector2((float)(distance * Math.Cos(angle) ), (float)(distance * Math.Sin(angle))) + centre ;
    }
```

Comment: Set end angle to 2*pi. The spacing between points in radiants is your angleincrement.  To get the Euclidean distance between two point the easiest way is calculating the distance of any two neighbouring points of the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `endAngle` to 2π. The spacing between points **in radians** is your `angleIncrement`.
To get the Euclidean distance between two point the easiest way is calculating the distance between any two neighbouring points of the result.

Also convert `endAngle` and `angelIncrement` to float.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When i do this
private int endAngle = 2 * (int)Math.PI ;

i dont get anything if ammount of points is higher than 6. Why?

Comment: @Lautaro because your `angleIncrementation` is `int` and you're doing integer division when assigning to it. Make `angleIncrementation` and `endAngle` a `double` and use radians (from 0 to 2π) instead of degrees as Archy suggested. `double endAngle = 2*Math.PI; double angleIncrementation;`

Comment: Thanks for formatting, I did write that on my phone, same reason I made a comment by mistake :)